# How to compare the first column to the second column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a problem on my schoolwork. My goal is I want to compare the first column, first row and second column, second row.

I'm new to pandas so I have tried browsing answers on the internet but sadly there isn't. I have think of a way which is I have a converted pandas into a array and store the first column to the first array and second column to the second array.

```
first_array = [4,10,17,24,82,93,35,40,49,71,78]
last_array = [9,16,23,29,89,97,39,48,57,77,85]
```

and after that i've popped the first number of first_array which is 4 then insert a 0 into the last which looks likes this

```
first_array = [10,17,24,82,93,35,40,49,71,78, 0]
last_array =  [ 9,16,23,29,89,97,39,48,57,77,85]
```

and a little bit of for loop which is

```
if first_array < last_array:
   print ("===")
```

but it seems that my logic is correct but there's a slight wrong with the output i'm expecting

```
['10', '17', '24', '82', '93', '35', '40', '49', '71', '78', '0']
['9', '16', '23', '29', '89', '97', '39', '48', '57', '77', '85']
===
['17', '24', '82', '93', '35', '40', '49', '71', '78', '0']
['16', '23', '29', '89', '97', '39', '48', '57', '77', '85']
['24', '82', '93', '35', '40', '49', '71', '78', '0']
['23', '29', '89', '97', '39', '48', '57', '77', '85']
['82', '93', '35', '40', '49', '71', '78', '0']
['29', '89', '97', '39', '48', '57', '77', '85']
['93', '35', '40', '49', '71', '78', '0']
['89', '97', '39', '48', '57', '77', '85']
['35', '40', '49', '71', '78', '0']
['97', '39', '48', '57', '77', '85']
===
['40', '49', '71', '78', '0']
['39', '48', '57', '77', '85']
['49', '71', '78', '0']
['48', '57', '77', '85']
['71', '78', '0']
['57', '77', '85']
['78', '0']
['77', '85']
['0']
['85']
===
```

At the first "===" 10 isn't < 9 which makes me think. Did i miss something? Thank you in advance.

This is a snippet of my code. The print(join_tag) is the output i needed for this.

```
normalized_text = []
first_array = [10,17,24,82,93,35,40,49,71,78, 0]
last_array =  [ 9,16,23,29,89,97,39,48,57,77,85]
for word in normalized_text:
    join_tag = ' '.join(word)
    print (join_tag)
    if first_array < last_array:
        print ('===')
        first_array.pop(0)
        last_array.pop(0)
```

Expected output would be

```
['10', '17', '24', '82', '93', '35', '40', '49', '71', '78', '0']
['9', '16', '23', '29', '89', '97', '39', '48', '57', '77', '85']
['17', '24', '82', '93', '35', '40', '49', '71', '78', '0']
['16', '23', '29', '89', '97', '39', '48', '57', '77', '85']
['24', '82', '93', '35', '40', '49', '71', '78', '0']
['23', '29', '89', '97', '39', '48', '57', '77', '85']
['82', '93', '35', '40', '49', '71', '78', '0']
['29', '89', '97', '39', '48', '57', '77', '85']
['93', '35', '40', '49', '71', '78', '0']
['89', '97', '39', '48', '57', '77', '85']
['35', '40', '49', '71', '78', '0']
['97', '39', '48', '57', '77', '85']
===
['40', '49', '71', '78', '0']
['39', '48', '57', '77', '85']
['49', '71', '78', '0']
['48', '57', '77', '85']
['71', '78', '0']
['57', '77', '85']
['78', '0']
['77', '85']
['0']
['85']
===
```

Comment: What is `normalized_text`? When do you print `first_array` and `last_array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arrays contain strings.  Convert them to numbers.
In the first case '10' < '9' is true because the string '10' is alphabetically less than the string '9'

Answer (score 1):

if I understood your question correctly, you want to compare the 4 with the 16, right?

If so, putting the data back in a dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

first_array = np.array([4,10,17,24,82,93,35,40,49,71,78])
last_array = np.array([9,16,23,29,89,97,39,48,57,77,85])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((first_array, last_array)))
```

Then:

```
df.iloc[0, 0] < df.iloc[1, 1]
```

Will compare 4 < 16

To compare them all:

```
for i in range(len(df.columns)-1):
    print(df.iloc[0, i] < df.iloc[1, i+1])
```

Comment: Yep, but can't loop the df.iloc[0, 0] < df.iloc[1, 1]. After 4 comparing 16 i'll compare the other one which is 10 and 23.